# Markov Chains: Linking Transition Probabilities to Transition Times

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I was reading the following article on Markov Processes: [image]

Here, we are shown the probability distribution function of transitioning to some state "j", provided that we have spent some time "d" in some state "h". I have the following question:

- **Can we find out the "expected" amount of additional time that we will remain in state "h" - provided we have already spent some time "d" in "state h"?**

I thought of a very convoluted way of doing this - if possible, perhaps we could use the Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) algorithm to take many random samples from the conditional probability distribution function "F_hj(d)" - then, we can take the average value of these many random samples and consider this average value as the "expected amount of additional time we will remain in state h provided we have spent time d in state h"? But is there some other more straightforward way to do this? (e.g. closed form solution to whichever conditional distribution of whichever probability distribution you decide to use)

Thank you!

- https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v066i06